# ¿como puedo realizar una funcion que elimine elementos repetidos de una lista?

Tags: java, recursión

como puedo realizar un programa en java que use recursividad en el cual pueda eliminar los caracteres repetidos por ejemplo que pueda ingresar la palabra HOLA MUNDO, y me devuelva la cadena en este caso sin la letra O que se repite : HLAMUND

espero me puedan ayudar soy nuevo aprendiendo a programar.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Por favor, las preguntas DEBEN exponer el código que has intentado. Una pregunta que expone sólo un enunciado NO es bien recibida en este sitio. Debes demostrar lo que has intentado y exponer tu código aunque no funcione. Checa [este ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/GWcGhm40M) para que tengas una idea de posible solución. Muy buena suerte y bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

encontré este codigo que capaz si lo modificas te puede servir.

El codigo extrae las vocales de una palabra, fijate si podes modificarlo para que extraiga los caracteres repetidos.

```
static String vocales(String cadena) {
        String voc = "";
        char vocales[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

//recorro la cadena
        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
//recorro el array de vocales
            for (int j = 0; j < vocales.length; j++) {

                if (cadena.charAt(i) == vocales[j]) {
                    voc += vocales[j] + ", ";
                }
            }
        }

        return voc;
    }
```

Comment: Estimado eso no responde a la pregunta, además el ejercicio debe realizarse usando recursividad